# JBoss EAP 6.2: Exchange auth-method of war-file

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, war, jboss-eap-6

I have one application (packaged as war) for two customers running on JBoss EAP 6.2. One of them uses Basic JBoss Authentication, the other one Keycloak authentication provider.

Both war files are exactly the same with one difference: The WEB-INF/web.xml contains

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

respectively

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>keycloak</auth-method>
    <realm-name>application</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

I would like to prevent to build two different war files (because web.xml is inside of the war file) so I wondered how I can configure these lines in the JBoss configuration instead of in web.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `login-config` as below:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>${authentication.method}</auth-method>
    <realm-name>${authentication.realm}</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

And then pass those parameters as system properties when application server starts:

```
-Dauthentication.method=BASIC -Dauthentication.realm=ApplicationRealm
```

But you should remember that by default WildFly/JBoss will not replace variables in deployment descriptors. You should explicitly enable this option in your server configurations under `ee` subsystem. In *WildFly 13.0.0.Final* it's like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
    <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>true</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>

    <!-- remaining of the configurations -->
</subsystem>
```